# Interaction studio einstein recipe not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein, einstein-recommendations, interaction-studio

We have created a einstein recipe with only one ingredient "Any eligible item". We could see products coming from the website under catalog->Products too. The Recommendations are enabled in the Gear also. But when we simulate the recipe, no products are shown. It's been 2 days since we created the recipe and trained it.

Can someone please advise me what the issue could be?

Thanks in Advance,
Nikhila

Answer (score 1):

There is a good troubleshoot guide available in the Interaction Studio documents [here](https://doc.evergage.com/display/EKB/Troubleshoot+Recommendations) which can be your first call when troubleshooting any unexpected results during training of your Einstein Recipes.

I  created an Einstein Recipe with just the ingredient entry "Any eligible item". After simulating the recipe, I got shown results that I expected based on the affinities of the users added to the test group. Referencing back to the help documents, it might be useful for you to have a look at the affinities of the users you added to the test group that you used for simulating the recipe. It might be that that user has no affinities registered and as such the recipe can't make any recommendation.